# High CPU usage (300%) when inserting data with knex

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I want to insert large amounts of data to SQL Server via knex.  I've lowered the number of inserts at once and concurrency of inserts but I still end up with high CPU usage. Could it have something with knex starting a connection for each insert? Any input would be appreciated thanks.
This is the code I used to connect to the db.

```
client: "mssql",
    connection: {
      server: productionDbIp,
      user: productionDbUsername,
      password: productionDbPassword,
      database: productionDbName,
      options: {
        port: productionDbPort
      },
      pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }
    }
```

Here is the code used to que the inserts

```
const insertQue = new PQueue({ concurrency: 1 });

// format inserts returns an array of objects that are ready to be inserted
const [inserts] = await formatInserts(distinctData);

    const insertPromises = [];

    while (inserts.length > 0) {
      const insert = inserts.splice(0,10);

      try {
        insertPromises.push(
          insertQue.add(() => insertToDb(insert, 'tableName'))
        );

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    try {
      await Promise.all(insertPromises);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

async function insertToDb(data, table, numTry = 0) {
  try {
    return await knex(table).insert(data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (numTry > 3) {
      console.log(error);
      throw { message: `Error inserting data`, data };
    }
    return insertToDb(data, numTry + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about knex but have you tried calling a stored proc instead of a direct DB insert?

Comment: No I have not tried this. I'll look into it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search show this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/240204

So having 300% might not even be an issue. Your virtual core are gearing up to do their job. Since you are using async calls multiple proc can work together.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what is happening

Comment: Hello @ConnorRobertson please mark the answer to close your question : this will tidy up StackOverflow and help you when asking your next question.